# How do i in jQuery get td span value when clicking to increase RadNumericTextBox using spin buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have TABLE and within it i have several CELLS - PRICE, QUANTITY, TOTAL
When the RadNumericTextbox spin buttons are clicked id like to increase the TOTAL cell.

I have the following

```
   <tr>
        <td><a href="#" title="View Product Details"><asp:Label ID="LblTitleTableView" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></a></td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="LblWeightTableView" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label CssClass="TabPrice" ID="LblProdPriceTV" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtQuantity" CssClass="ProdDropDowns" RegisterWithScriptManager="true" Value="1" MinValue="1" runat="server" Width="50px" Type="Number" ShowSpinButtons="true" >
                <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
                <ClientEvents OnValueChanged="TabularProductQtyChanged"></ClientEvents>
            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
        </td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="LblTotalTableView" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                <asp:Image ID="AddBasketImgTableView" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/clients/14/themes/moredetails.png" AlternateText="Click for More Information" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

and the jQuery

```
     function TabularProductQtyChanged(sender, args) {
    var qty = args._initialValue;

}
```

I can get the quantity but am unable to traverse back up the DOM tree to get to the price which is inside the Label - LblProdPriceTV

Any ideas on how i can do this?

EDIT:

With the help from below ive been digging around in FireBug and realised the RadNumericTextBox control injects extra html markup. therefore i need to go further back up the DOM tree to get to the element i want - this in the end works:

```
    alert($('#' + elementID).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.ThisIsPrice').find('span').html());
```

Thank you for everyones help below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function TabularProductQtyChanged(sender, args) {
    var elementID = sender.id;
    alert($('#' + elementID).parent().next('td').find('span').html());
}
```

---

### Explanation

```
1. $('#' + elementID) - This means your `RadNumericTextBox`
2. $('#' + elementID).parent() mans the td. This contains `RadNumericTextBox`.
3. $('#' + elementID).parent().next('td').find('span') means the next td which 
                                       contains your Label control to traverse.
```

Comment: Hi, yes i also tried this approach, thinking i just go back up the DOM tree but my alert shows null.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you exactly working code but here's a recipe that I believe will get you there.

```
function TabularProductQtyChanged(sender, args) {
    var qty = args._initialValue;
    //Get the client-side id of the element that fired the event
    //There might be a method like sender.get_id() or simply a property such as sender.id;
    //use firebug and find out.
    var elementID = sender.id; 
    //The cell you need seems to be a span (asp labels are displayed as span elements)
    var price = $('#'+elementID).closest('.TabPrice').html();
}
```

Comment: again this is really odd i have uses your suggestion and put an alert against var price - alert(price); and i get null when there definatley is a vaule in there.

Comment: When i use this var price = $('#'+elementID).closest('.TabPrice'); And then alert(price); i get - [object Object] so it must be seeing the span tag, but as soon as i tap .html() or text() on the end i get nothing ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a demonstration using the `RadNumericTextBox`, but I can emulate it using the same elements that comprise the control. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WA4Ge/5/) to demonstrate.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function(){
       $("#table1 td input[type='text']").siblings("a").click(function(){
           $(this).parents("td").next(".total").css({ 
               width : $(this).hasClass("up") ? "300px" : "200px" 
           });
       }); 
    });​    
</script>
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- RadNumericTextBox Start -->
            <span>
                <span>
                    <!-- the input -->
                    <input type="text" id="txt1" /> 
                    <!-- spin buttons -->
                    <a href="#" class="up">Up</a> 
                    <a href="#" class="down">Down</a> 
                </span>
            </span>
            <!-- RadNumericTextBox End -->
        </td>            
        <td class="total">TOTALS HERE</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Comment: i have just tried your example and again cant get it to work, i can see the fiddle demo working fine. I think it has to be something to with how i build this table. We use a bit of a unorthodox approach as a aspx page loads in each row as a ascx page - kind of reinventing the repeater, cant change it as this is what ive been dealt with.

Comment: No problem. Can you revise your question and provide some sort of an example? The selector probably just needs to be tweaked a little bit. Sounds like it's not drilling all the way down to the `RadTextBox`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, figured it out, when the Telerik control is used it injects a lot of markup into my table cell, i just needed to traverse up the DOM tree by about 7 .parent() levels, got it working ok now thankyou.

Comment: @NeilHodges: I think you missed something in my example. That's why I used `parents("td")` instead of `parent()`. Using `parents("td")` will traverse the tree until it finds the nearest `td` element.

Comment: Ah yes your right - but the Telerik controls markup is within a div and a table so it would not of worked, using Firebug i relised that the extra markup inserted another table within me td cell.